# How can I install an app on one of the hundred ad hoc installations I am allowed?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, device

I've been reading and working through https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions.html, right up until the point where it says to drag the *.mobileprovision to iTunes, and it says, "Double-click the app archive (the file with the .ipa extension)."

I am presently unable to find a program of my own having a file with a .ipa extension, and therefore unable AFAICT to run my app on an iOS device yet.

The documentation I was reading is legacy documentation, but I didn't notice a link to anything newer.

I have several things in place now, including a Testing_.*mobileprovision dragged into iTunes, but I am having trouble identifying the last step(s) to get my app to run on my machine.

What can I do next to get the app to run on my machine?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You have to export the app using Xcode Organizer, Archives, Distribute, Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Depoloyment. Sign it with your Ad hoc profile. Then you will have an ipa to install.

Comment: Where do I find Xcode Organizer? I've looked through the menus and such and haven't found it.

Comment: Shift,Apple Key, 2. Or just Window, Organizer. From inside Xcode

Comment: Thank you; I have Organizer open. When I select Archives, I see an empty window, that just says "No Archives." - I don't see where there is a "Distribute" that applies to my project. If I click "Projects", I see my project, but I don't see how to copy it to Archives.

Comment: You have to select Product, Archive, in order to build to you archive folder.

Comment: The Product / Archive menu item is grayed out both from organizer and the code editing window. What do I need to do to enable Product / Archive?

Comment: You have to make sure that you have 'iOS Device' as the targeted running operation. You cannot have a simulator selected. Once you do that Archive should be available for action.

Comment: I tried two specific iOS devices; I didn't see a lone 'iOS Device' among what were otherwise labeled as simulator options. So far, nothing I have tried has had anything appear under Archive.